# Single positional indexer is out-of-bounds error reading from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, intellilock

I'm attempting to read a .csv and write a new column. Whenever I call the function add(), the index error appears on Line 7.

```
def add():
    data = pd.read_csv('log.csv')
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if 'log' in file:
            continue
        df = pd.read_csv(open(file))
        val = data.loc[data['Num'] == file.split('.csv')[0], 'SAT'].iloc[0]
        ########more code using val#############
add()
```

Comment: could explain what you trying to do in line 7 .

Comment: I noticed that when I added a 'return' the error doesn't appear. However, it only returns one file.

I have three files that I'm trying to read/write/display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739634/8208006 please check your csv file