# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds index error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tqdm

```
user_ratings_matrix = training_df.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='rating')
users = user_ratings_matrix.index.values 

print('Creating corated data frame...')
with open('similarities/UsersCorated.csv', 'w') as result_file:
    print('user1,user2,corated', file=result_file)

    print('Calculating corated between users...')
    for u1 in tqdm(users, total=len(users)):
        for u2 in users:

            movies_u1 = ~np.isnan(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u1 - 1])
            movies_u2 = ~np.isnan(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u2 - 1])

            same_movies = np.logical_and(movies_u1, movies_u2)
            num_same_movies = list(same_movies).count(True)
        print(f"{u1},{u2},{num_same_movies}", file=result_file)
```

---

error

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 
>   ----> 2 Similarities_Functions.Corated_Matrix()
>         3 Similarities_Functions.Corated_Similarity()
>         4 
>         5 print('finished!!!')
>
> ~/Documents/PhD/IntelliSys19/journal/ColdStart_Experiment/Similarities_Functions.py
>   in Corated_Matrix()
>       145             for u2 in users:
>       146                 ratings1 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u1 - 1].values))
>   --> 147                 ratings2 = np.nan_to_num(np.array(user_ratings_matrix.iloc[u2 - 1].values))
>       148 
>       149                 sim = pearsonr(ratings1, ratings2)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    1371     1372             maybe_callable = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
>   -> 1373             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)    1374     1375     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
>   _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1828     1829             # validate the location
>   -> 1830             self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)    1831     1832             return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
>   _is_valid_integer(self, key, axis)    1711         l = len(ax)    1712         if key >= l or key < -l:
>   -> 1713             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")    1714         return True    1715
>
> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iloc giving 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 1):

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I believe that this is simply saying that one of your iloc statements is looking up something that doesn't exist. If your DataFrame is 5 rows long, iloc[5, 0] would give out-of-bounds. This is because the last row would be iloc[4, 0], as it begins counting from 0.