# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds Fitbit Python

Tags: python, fitbit

I am currently working with the Fitbit Web API. I'm basically working with the code from [here](https://github.com/yashatgit/fitbit-analyzer/blob/master/Fitbit_Data_Collection.ipynb). I'm trying to simply just access all my data that Fitbit has and I'm running into an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
Date today is :2019-10-04
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/sleepbit/main2.py", line 228, in <module>
    database = fetchData(database)
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/sleepbit/main2.py", line 210, in fetchData
    lastEntryDate = getLastEntryDate(database)
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/sleepbit/main2.py", line 38, in getLastEntryDate
    lastDateEntry = database.iloc[-1]['Date']
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/IRC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/IRC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2230, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Users/sunny/PycharmProjects/IRC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2139, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Here's my code:

```
import fitbit
import gather_keys_oauth2 as Oauth2
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np


CLIENT_ID = '22B58Z'
CLIENT_SECRET = '69ea96ed78c676d5bb9023696597b4cc'

server = Oauth2.OAuth2Server(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
server.browser_authorize()

ACCESS_TOKEN = str(server.fitbit.client.session.token['access_token'])
REFRESH_TOKEN = str(server.fitbit.client.session.token['refresh_token'])

##Build Auth Clients
auth2_client = fitbit.Fitbit(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, oauth2=True, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                             refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN, system='en_GB')

# NEed this seeparately because version 1 doesn't give sleep breakdown
auth2_client_new = fitbit.Fitbit(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, oauth2=True, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
                                 refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN, system='en_GB')
auth2_client_new.API_VERSION = 1.2
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
databaseFilename = 'database_main.xls'


def connectAndLoadDb():
    print("Connecting database...")
    database = pd.read_excel(databaseFilename)
    print("Database connected!")
    return database;


def getLastEntryDate(database):
   lastDateEntry = database.iloc[-1]['Date']
   lastDateEntry = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastDateEntry, DATE_FORMAT)
   return lastDateEntry


def addEntriesInDB(dictionary, database):
    # print(dictionary)
    database = database.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
    return addEntriesInDB;


def writeDbToExcelFile(database):
    print('Writing database to filename: ' + databaseFilename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(databaseFilename)
    database.to_excel(writer, 'main')
    writer.save()
    print('Database updated with new entries!!')


def prettyPrintDate(date):
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT);


# x[4] if len(x) == 4 else 'No'
def safeGet(obj, key, defaultVal=np.nan):
    return obj.get(key, defaultVal)


def percent(val):
    return np.ceil(val * 100)


def filterArrObj(arrList, keyName, keyValue):
    for arrItem in arrList:
        if arrItem.get(keyName) == keyValue:
            return arrItem
    return {}


def mergeDicts(dicts):
    super_dict = {}
    for singleDict in dicts:
        for k, v in singleDict.items():
            super_dict[k] = v
    return super_dict


def getActivities(date):
    activitiyResponse = auth2_client.activities(date=date)

    activitySummary = activitiyResponse['summary'];
    activityData = {
        'Calories Burned': safeGet(activitySummary, 'caloriesOut'),
        'Calories BMR': safeGet(activitySummary, 'caloriesBMR'),
        'Resting Heart Rate': safeGet(activitySummary, 'restingHeartRate'),
        'Steps': safeGet(activitySummary, 'steps'),
        'Distance (Km)': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('distances', []), 'activity', 'total').get('distance',
                                                                                                     np.nan),
        'Elevation (Ft)': activitySummary['elevation'],
        'Floors': activitySummary['floors'],
        'Minutes Sedentary': activitySummary['sedentaryMinutes'],
        'Minutes Lightly Active': activitySummary['lightlyActiveMinutes'],
        'Minutes Fairly Active': activitySummary['fairlyActiveMinutes'],
        'Minutes Very Active': activitySummary['veryActiveMinutes'],
        'Activity Calories': activitySummary['activityCalories'],
        'Active Score': activitySummary['activeScore'],
        'Cardio minutes': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Cardio').get('minutes',
                                                                                                        np.nan),
        'Cardio calories': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Cardio').get('caloriesOut',
                                                                                                         np.nan),
        'Fat Burn minutes': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Fat Burn').get('minutes',
                                                                                                            np.nan),
        'Fat Burn calories': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Fat Burn').get(
            'caloriesOut', np.nan),
        'Peak minutes': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Peak').get('minutes', np.nan),
        'Peak calories': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Peak').get('caloriesOut',
                                                                                                     np.nan),
        'Normal Cardio minutes': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Out of Range').get(
            'minutes', np.nan),
        'Normal Cardio calories': filterArrObj(activitySummary.get('heartRateZones', []), 'name', 'Out of Range').get(
            'caloriesOut', np.nan),
    }

    return activityData


def getSleep(date):
    sleepResponse = auth2_client_new.sleep(date=date)

    sleepData = {}
    for sleepLog in sleepResponse.get('sleep', []):
        if sleepLog.get('isMainSleep'):
            sleepLevelsSummary = sleepLog.get('levels', {}).get('summary', {})

            sleepData['Sleep Efficiency'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'efficiency')
            sleepData['Minutes Asleep'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'minutesAsleep')
            sleepData['Minutes to fall asleep'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'minutesToFallAsleep')
            sleepData['Sleep Start time'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'startTime')
            sleepData['Sleep End time'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'endTime')

            sleepData['Time in bed'] = safeGet(sleepLog, 'timeInBed')

            sleepData['Minutes Deep sleep'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('deep', {}), 'minutes')
            sleepData['Deep sleep count'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('deep', {}), 'count')
            sleepData['% Deep sleep'] = percent(
                safeGet(sleepData, 'Minutes Deep sleep', 0) / safeGet(sleepData, 'Time in bed', 0))

            sleepData['Minutes Light sleep'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('light', {}), 'minutes')
            sleepData['Light sleep count'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('light', {}), 'count')
            sleepData['% Light sleep'] = percent(
                safeGet(sleepData, 'Minutes Light sleep', 0) / safeGet(sleepData, 'Time in bed', 0))

            sleepData['Minutes REM sleep'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('rem', {}), 'minutes')
            sleepData['REM sleep count'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('rem', {}), 'count')
            sleepData['% REM sleep'] = percent(
                safeGet(sleepData, 'Minutes REM sleep', 0) / safeGet(sleepData, 'Time in bed', 0))

            sleepData['Minutes Asleep'] = sleepData['Minutes Deep sleep'] + sleepData['Minutes Light sleep'] + \
                                          sleepData['Minutes REM sleep']
            sleepData['Minutes Awake'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('wake', {}), 'minutes')
            sleepData['Minutes Awake count'] = safeGet(sleepLevelsSummary.get('wake', {}), 'count')
    return sleepData


def getDateData(date):
    weekDayNum = date.isoweekday()
    return {
        'Day of Week': weekDayNum,
        'Is Weekday': weekDayNum < 6,
        'Is Weekend': weekDayNum > 5,
        'Date': prettyPrintDate(date)
    };


def fetchAllData(date):
    dateStr = prettyPrintDate(date)

    print("Fetching fitbit data for: " + dateStr)

    nextDate = date + timedelta(days=1)
    sleepData = getSleep(prettyPrintDate(nextDate))

    activitiesData = getActivities(dateStr)
    dateData = getDateData(date)

    mergedData = mergeDicts([sleepData, activitiesData, dateData])
    return mergedData


database = connectAndLoadDb()


def shouldFetchDataForProvidedDate(providedDate, todaysDate, API_COUNTER):
    return (providedDate < todaysDate) and API_COUNTER < 100;


def fetchAndAppendToDb(date, database):
    mergedData = fetchAllData(date)
    database = database.append(mergedData, ignore_index=True)
    return database;


def fetchData(database, refetchAll=False):
    API_COUNTER = 0

    todaysDate = datetime.datetime.today()

    print("Date today is :" + prettyPrintDate(todaysDate))

    if refetchAll == True:
        lastEntryDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-06-23', DATE_FORMAT)
    else:
        lastEntryDate = getLastEntryDate(database)

    print("Last entry in Db is of :" + prettyPrintDate(lastEntryDate))
    print("----------------------------------------------")

    dateToFetch = lastEntryDate + timedelta(days=1)

    while shouldFetchDataForProvidedDate(dateToFetch, todaysDate, API_COUNTER):
        database = fetchAndAppendToDb(dateToFetch, database)
        dateToFetch = dateToFetch + timedelta(days=1)
        API_COUNTER = API_COUNTER + 1

    print("----------------------------------------------")
    print("Data fill completed!")
    return database


# database = fetchData(database, refetchAll = True)
database = fetchData(database)

writeDbToExcelFile(database)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much! I'm a little confused as to what the error even is and how to start approaching to fix it. I'm a little new to the Fitbit API and the documentation for it with Python is a little scarce, so I'm struggling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iloc giving 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds)

Comment: hard to tell because this isn't really an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but I'd guess that your `database` variable is empty