# Python iloc giving indexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds in simple for loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe as given below:

```
df = 
          0
1      0.993995
2      1.111068
3      1.760940
.
.
.
49    40.253574
50    40.664486
51    41.083962
```

I am iterating through each row and print each element. My code is given below:

```
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    print(df[0].iloc[idx])
```

Present output:

```
1.111068
1.76094
2.691832
.
.
40.664486
41.083962
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-80539a9081e5>", line 2, in <module>
    print(darkdf[0].iloc[idx])

  File "C:\Users\MM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1500, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File "C:\Users\MM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2230, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)

  File "C:\Users\MM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2139, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Why this simple function is giving error. Someone could help me to understand what the error is saying?

Comment: This link from a previous stackoverflow question might be helpful! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: I am actually doing row wise operation. Here I showed simple print function to explain the problem I am facing. Print is not my actual objective. This link talks about Print. How to iterate through rows

Comment: Mmm tricky, I tried it on my own and it is fine. Could you print(index, df[0].iloc[idx]) seems like the index is not consistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iloc giving 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First correct way for select is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df)
          0
1  0.993995
2  1.111068
3  1.760940

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    print(df.loc[idx, 0])
0.9939950000000001
1.111068
1.7609400000000002
```

Problem in your solution:

If use [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) function it select by position, not by labels.

So you want select 4.th row by selecting:

```
df[0].iloc[3]
```

but there is not `4.th` (python counts from 0, so for select 4.th row need 3) row so raised error.

If use:

```
df[0].loc[3]
```

it working like you expected, because selecting index `3` (not position 4 which not exist) and column `0`, but better is use:

```
df.loc[idx, 0]
```

because [evaluation order matters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters).

Comment: Hi, Happy to see you reply to my question. Could you please educate me why I am getting error for simple iloc function?

Comment: Now your response educated me about iloc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried following example and understood the difference: ` df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10,20,30]},index=[2,4,6])
    for idx,row in df1.iterrows():
        print(df1.loc[idx,"A"])`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `loc` instead of `iloc`. `iloc` uses the zero-based row number, not indices. Your code is passing the indices, which go over the range of the zero-based row numbers, hence out-of-bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please enlighten me, both row number or index are same right?