# Error: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Please help me resolve this error:

> 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Error comes in line `if instru[6:9] =="HDFC":`
Instruments columns contains name of schemes

```py
df=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=fund,skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4],usecols=[2,3,5,6,7,8])

df.columns=["instruments","isin","industry_rating","qty","mktval","pct"]
index = 0
check = 0

for instru in df["instruments"]:
    if instru[6:9] =="HDFC":
        check = 1 
        break
    index += 1

if check == 1:
    print(index)

df.iloc[[index],[1,2,3]] = ["Additional","Additional",1]

print(df.iloc[index])
```

Comment: Could you write your code in a readable format ?

Comment: `instru` is apparently a float. And even if it were a string, `instru[6:9]` would only return 3 characters, so it would never equal `HDFC`

Comment: @SidouMahmoud df=pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=fund,skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4],usecols=[2,3,5,6,7,8])

df.columns=["instruments","isin","industry_rating","qty","mktval","pct"]
df=df[['instruments','industry_rating','isin','qty','mktval','pct']]



df['date']=date1
print(df.columns)


index = 0
check = 0
for instru in df["instruments"]:
    if instru[6:9] =="HDFC":
        check = 1
        break
    index += 1
if check == 1:
    print(index)
    df.iloc[[index],[1,2,3]] = ["Additional","Additional",1]
    
print(df.iloc[index])

Comment: @DavidBuck can u please tell me the solution.. I saw the same code somewhere but its working fine there. The type of instru is panda series object.

Comment: Firstly, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61818834/edit) your question to add additional information, as it's basically unreadable in the comments. Second, just inspect `df["instruments"]` and make sure it contains what you think it should contain. If it's mostly strings with the occasional float, you'll have to handle that in your code.

Comment: @DavidBuck yes, it contains strings with the occasional float. How can i handle that?

Answer (score 1):

```
index = 0
check = 0

for instru in df["instruments"]:
    if str(instru)[6:9] =="HDFC":
        check = 1 
        break
    index += 1
```

`instru` is float so type cast it to string.
 `str(instru)[6:9]` returns 3 character only so provide `df["instruments"]`

Comment: Gives error-- raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to check values if they are strings, the (and as a float can never be `"HDFC"`), rather than cast everything to str, you can simply check if `instru` is a string before doing to string comparison. You can do that with the [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) command like this.

```
for instru in df["instruments"]:
    if isinstance(instru, string) and instru[6:9] =="HDFC":
        check = 1 
        break
    index += 1
```

Bear in mind that `instru[6:9]` only returns 3 characters (position 9 is not included) so you will need to correct the slice to contain the correct four characters.

Comment: The solution was to use try and except block. Thanks for ur valuable comments.