# I am trying to add in data to an existing PPT template using the python-pptx package

Tags: python, python-pptx

```py
for x in range(row_count):
        for y in range(5):
            i = x // lines_per_slide
            z = [prs.slides[i].shapes[z].name for z in range(len(prs.slides[i].shapes))].index("name_of_table_in_ppt")
            line_num = x % lines_per_slide
            if y == 4:
                try:
                    formatted_value = '{:.2f}'.format(data.iloc[x, y])
                except:
                    formatted_value = ""
            else:
                formatted_value = str(data.iloc[x, y])
```

However, I seem to get the following error message on the last line:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try adding a `print(data.iloc, x, y)` line before the problematic line and see what it tells you. This problem looks to be coming from your `data.iloc` structure having either fewer than `x` rows or fewer than `y` columns when you get the error. Nothing to do with `python-pptx` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds. You're trying to access more data than your dataframe has.