# Yfinance script - Getting single positional indexer is out-of-bounds error

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, yfinance

I'm trying to run yfinance to get current price, and day change of world indices. However, prev_close seems to be causing the error below:

"IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"

How can I fix this? I believe this is because the dimensions of the dataframe are off, but I'm not sure how.

Please see my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['^FTSE','^GSPTSE','^DJI','^GSPC','^GDAXI','^KS11','^IBEX','^GSPTSE','^AXJO','^STI','000001.SS','399001.SZ','000132.SS','000852.SS','^N225','^NSEI','^BSESN','^HSI','^GSPC','^IXIC','^RUT']
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_yahoo = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    data = ticker_yahoo.history()
    last_quote = '%.2f' % data['Close'].iloc[-1]
    prev_close = '%.2f' % data['Close'].iloc[-2]

    change1 = float(last_quote) - float(prev_close)
    change = '%.2f' % change1

    percent_change1 = ((float(last_quote) - float(prev_close)) / float(prev_close)) * 100
    percent_change = '%.2f' % percent_change1 + '%'


    print(ticker + ': ' + last_quote, change, percent_change)
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739327/iloc-giving-indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds

Answer (score 0):

Removed items: '000132.SS','000852.SS' from the tickers list. Turns out yfinance is only returning 1 row of data for those two items.